# Implementing table insertion into Word using Office for JS (officejs)

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

Working on a project aiming to convert some C# based Word Add-in into JavaScript using officejs.

Quite surprised that after 5 years of development officejs API is not quite there in terms of coverage compared to C# API.

I am struggling how to translate the following C# Word API code into JavaScript based API. Seems that a lot of functionality is simply not there.

How can the following code be converted to Javascript to achieve the same level of end state functionality?

```
     MsWord.Table tblchart = rng.Tables.Add(rng, NumRows: 1, NumColumns: 1,
       AutoFitBehavior: MsWord.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitFixed);
     tblchart.AllowPageBreaks = false;
     tblchart.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
     tblchart.Borders.InsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
     tblchart.Borders.Shadow = false;

     tblchart.TopPadding = tblchart.BottomPadding = tblchart.LeftPadding = 0f;
     tblchart.RightPadding = application.InchesToPoints(0.02f);
     tblchart.PreferredWidthType = MsWord.WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPoints;
     tblchart.set_Style(WordStyles.Table);
     tblchart.Range.set_Style(WordStyles.TableMaster);
     tblchart.Rows.WrapAroundText = System.Convert.ToInt32(false);
     tblchart.PreferredWidth = _Imagewidth;
     tblchart.Descr = _description;
     tblchart.Rows[1].AllowBreakAcrossPages = 0;
     tblchart.Rows[1].Range.set_Style(WordStyles.Figure);
     tblchart.Rows[1].Range.Text = "";
     tblchart.Rows.SetLeftIndent(LeftIndent: application.InchesToPoints(_leftIndent), RulerStyle: WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
```

Comment: all the Table/TableCollection/TableRow/TableCell/InsertTable related methods are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.table?view=word-js-preview would you please take a look? I assume many of the APIs you needed are listed there.

Comment: @MSFT-Jipyua I know they are there but seems like majority of the functionality from C# API used in my code sample does not have any direct coverage...thus my question. There are no API to set the border attributes, no API to get the range from the table...no API to get range of table row....

Comment: Actually there are APIs to set the border attribute, please see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.tableborder?view=word-js-preview.  and api to get the range https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.table?view=word-js-preview#word-word-table-getrange-member(1). Please look through all the apis in detail and confirm whether it contains your needed ones.

Comment: yes, there is API to get range , just not the range of a table row. Please point me to officejs API where I can find mentions of autoFitBehaviour for table, or set  line style or shadow on the border. There is NOTHING along these lines....how do I allowBreakAcrossPage for Table Row? how do I set indent on the table row collection ? How do I move range by 1 or two characters? How do I set wrapAroundText or table rows collection? Pretty much every single line of C# Word API code in the question has no coverage in Office for JS....

Comment: hi, there are still some gaps on the word apis and we are working on adding more. We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions). Please add your request there. Feature requests are considered when we go through our planning process. Thanks.